# C parser program to add list of numbers separated by ; over multiple lines taking input using read()

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I want to write a program that takes numbers as inputs over multiple lines that are identified/separated by let's say ; character and print out their sum(s). Example:

```
1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;(enter)
10 11 12;(enter)
exit(enter)
```

And I want the expected output to be exactly like:

```
List 1: 6 (sum of 1 2 3)
List 2: 15 (sum of 4 5 6)
List 3: 24 (sum of 7 8 9)
List 4: 33 (sum of 10 11 12)
```

`sum of a b c`, printing out this is not necessary, but their result as number is (enter), i.e. I'm pressing enter/getting to new line.

I am terminating when user types exit. But I am getting segmentation fault error in my code. Plus in this code the sum is also getting wrong values (I tried it separately).

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    char *b;
    int sum = 0;
    int rc;
    int i = 1;

    while (strcasecmp(b, "exit") != 0) {
        char buff[50];
        rc = read(0, buff, 50);
        if (rc == -1) {
            perror("");
            exit(0);
        }
        char *a = buff;
        b = strtok(a, "\n");
        char *c = strtok(b, ";");
        while (c != NULL) {
            char *d = strtok(c, " ");
            while (d != NULL) {
                int a = atoi(d);
                sum += a;
                d = strtok(NULL, " ");
                printf("List %d: %d", i, sum);
                i++;
            }
            c = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are getting segfault because `b` is not pointing anywhere also in next iterations `buff` will go out of scope.

Comment: `rc = read(0, buff, 50);`  will not produce a properly-terminated string, yet `char *a = buff; b = strtok(a, "\n");` assumes a properly `'\0'`-terminated string.  You also appear to be assuming `read()` stops at newline characters.  It doesn't.  `read()` also returns `ssize_t` and not `int`.

Comment: read doesn't stop on newline character? :/
b = strtok(a, "\n") will replace \n in a with '\0' (from a)anyway. Thats not important here I guess.
read return ssize I know but again in this scope its not that important either

Comment: The `read()` system call doesn't necessarily stop at a newline character.  If the input comes from a terminal where you're typing, it will return a line of data (as long as that line is no longer than the amount of data requested), but if the input comes from a disk file (for example), it will read the requested number of bytes, regardless of whether there are zero, one or many newlines in that expanse.  It won't null terminate the input — it will tell you how many bytes it read.  Note that it reports EOF by returning 0, not -1.

Comment: *`b = strtok(a, "\n")` will replace \n in a with `'\0'`*  It won't if there's no `'\n'` character in the input buffer.  You need to read [the documentation for `read()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) and **understand** how it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `b` is an uninitialized pointer, reading and writing through it have undefined behavior, most likely the cause of the segmentation fault.
- you should not use the POSIX low level functions to read input, it is non portable and the input might not be read in line chunks and will not be null terminated... Furthermore, a `-1` return value is not always an error.

Use `fgets()` or other standard stream functions.

Here is a simple solution if you can assume that lists do not span multiple lines and are always terminated by `;`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int sumlist(int n, char *str) {
    char *p, *q;
    int sum = 0, term;
    for (p = str;; p = q) {
        p += strspn(p, " \t\n");  // skip blanks
        if (*p == '\0')
            break;
        term = strtol(p, &q, 10);
        if (q == p) {
            printf("invalid input: %s\n", str);
            return -1;
        }
        sum += term;
    }
    printf("List %d: %d (sum of %s)\n", n, sum, str);
    return 0;
}  

int main() {
    char buf[200];
    int n = 1;
    char *p, *q;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) {
        for (p = str;;) {
            p += strspn(p, " \t\n");  // skip initial blanks
            if (*p == '\0')
                break;
            q = strchr(p, ';');
            if (q != NULL)
                *q = '\0';
            if (p == q) {
                p = q + 1;  // skip empty lists
                continue;
            }
            if (!strcmp(p, "exit"))
                break;
            sumlist(n++, p);
            if (q == NULL)
                break;
            p = q + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you cannot use `fgets()` or any standard stream functions, re-write your own version, reading one byte at a time from the OS handle with `read()` and carefully test for potential signal interrupts:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *my_gets(int hd, char *buf, size_t size) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i + 1 < size;) {
        ssize_t n = read(hd, &buf[i], 1);
        if (n != 1) {
            if (n == -1 && errno == EINTR)
               continue;
            break;
        }
        if (buf[i++] == '\n')
            break;
    }
    if (i == 0)
        return NULL;
    buf[i] = '\0';
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char buf[200];
    int n = 1;
    char *p, *q;

    while (my_gets(0, buf, sizeof buf) {
        for (p = str;;) {
            p += strspn(p, " \t\n");  // skip initial blanks
            if (*p == '\0')
                break;
            q = strchr(p, ';');
            if (q != NULL)
                *q = '\0';
            if (p == q) {
                p = q + 1;  // skip empty lists
                continue;
            }
            if (!strcmp(p, "exit"))
                break;
            sumlist(n++, p);
            if (q == NULL)
                break;
            p = q + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getchar` and parse the integers on the go as below, without `strtok`.

```
int main() {

    int sum = 0; int rc; int i = 0, j = 0;
    char buff[50] = "";

   while(1)  {

      if (i>= sizeof buff) break; //not enough memory

      if (read(STDIN_FILENO, &buff[i], 1) < 1)  {break;} //read error

      if (strcasecmp(buff, "exit") == 0) break;
      else if (buff[i] == ';'){
            buff[i] = '\0';
            int a = atoi(buff);
            sum += a;
            printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
            sum = 0;
            i = 0;
            memset(buff, 0 , sizeof buff);
      }
      else if (buff[i] == ' '){
            buff[i] = '\0';
            int a = atoi(buff);
            sum += a;
            i = 0;
      }
      else if (buff[i] != '\n'){
        i++;
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kiranBiradr: interesting approach, but why don't you test the return value of `read`? You cannot properly check for end of file from the buffer contents alone. Furthermore, you do not prevent buffer overflow on overlong input data. Also the check for `exit` seems incorrect as you do not null terminate the buffer before `strcasecmp`, hence `exit` will not be detected if the last number had more than 4 digits.

Comment: @kiranBiradr:it is risky to duplicate hard-coded constants such as `50`, you should instead use `sizeof buff`. Also the OP uses `;` instead of `#` as a list delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

There are already working solutions here, but I'd like to suggest another one that might be helpful to understand some concepts.

Although you cannot use `getc` and `ungetc`, I would still address your problem in a way that uses the concept of a `get_buf`. My solution reads a character at a time and tries to turn it into a valid token that the main loop can `switch` on. In my opinion, that's a nice way to handle the parsing of simple 'languages' like the one you want to interpret. Also, it is pretty extensible & it's easy to add additional tokens (e.g. math operations like `+ - / *`).

As a quick description what's happening: In `get_char`, a single byte is read from `STDIN` whenever the internal buffer is empty. If it is not, the character that's on the buffer is returned. This functionality is used by `get_valid_token` which returns either your delimiter `;` or a (potentially multi-digit) number. Being able to 'unget' a character is required here. In `main`, we continuously get tokens and perform the appropriate action, nicely separating getting and interpretation of tokens. Obviously, this a quick and dirty program, but it might work for you.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUF_SIZ 2 /* get_buf never buffers more than one char by design */

static char get_buf[BUF_SIZ];
static char *get_buf_ptr = get_buf;

char get_char(int fd)
{
    char c;

    /* check buffer first */
    if (!(get_buf == get_buf_ptr))
        return *get_buf_ptr--;

    /* if buffer is empty, read from STDIN */
    if ((read(fd, &c, 1)) == -1) {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }

    return c;
}

void unget_char(char c)
{
    *(++get_buf_ptr) = c;
}

void flush(int fd)
{
    char c;

    do {
        read(fd, &c, 1);
    } while (c != '\n');
}

char is_exit()
{
    if ((get_char(STDIN_FILENO)) != 'x') return 0;
    if ((get_char(STDIN_FILENO)) != 'i') return 0;
    if ((get_char(STDIN_FILENO)) != 't') return 0;
    flush(STDIN_FILENO); /* remove already buffered input */
    return 1;
}

char *get_valid_token(void)
{
    char c;
    char *out;
    char *out_ptr;

    out_ptr = out = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZ);
    while (1) {
        c = get_char(STDIN_FILENO);

        if (c == ';') {
            *out = ';';
            break;
        } else if (isdigit(c)) {
            *out = c;
            out_ptr++;

            /* get the rest of the digit */
            while (1) {
                c = get_char(STDIN_FILENO);
                if (isdigit(c)) {
                    *out_ptr++ = c;
                } else {
                    unget_char(c);
                    break;
                }
            }
            *out_ptr = '\0';
            break;
        } else if (c == 'e') {
            if (is_exit())
                exit(0);
        }
    };
    return out;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *t;
    int sum;

    sum = 0;
    while ((t = get_valid_token())) {
        switch (*t) {
            case ';':
                fprintf(stderr, "sum: %d\n", sum);
                sum = 0;
                break;
            default:
                sum += atoi(t);
                break;
        }
        free(t);
    }

    return 0;
}
```